# Multiple VLANs with PAT

Tags: vlan, nat

I'd like to know if it's acceptable/possible to use PAT with multiple VLANs, by using the same translated IP address for all VLANs.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you’re trying to do?

Comment: I have 4 VLANs that use private IPv4 addresses, and I want to connect them to the internet. I want to know if it's okay for me to use PAT and assign 1 public IP address to all 4 VLANs or do I have to use one public IP address for each.  Which is better?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you refer to NAT/NAPT.

Possible? Definitely. You can use a boundary NAT router and then route between VLANs plainly.

Acceptable? That depends on your requirements and policies. NAT is normally only deemed acceptable when there's a real need to translate addresses, e.g. between public and private address space. Since NAT breaks the original end-to-end paradigm it should be avoided whenever possible.